# Get java script value from asp.net custom control textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, custom-controls, clientid

I have developed an asp.net custom control using text box, and its used in different places in a form, how can i get the text box value from different custom control.

I am using following syntax but its not working.

following propetly added to custom control class -

```
public TextBox ObjTextBox
{
    get { return objTextBox; }
}
```

following code using to get custom control value

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function met1() { 
        var objTextBox = document.getElementById('<%=MyTextBox1.ObjTextBox.ClientID %>'); 
        alert(objTextBox.value); 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: log error if any please. or what is alerted?

Comment: its saying floowing error - ": 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ClientID' and no extension method 'ClientID' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: appears that `MyTextBox1.ObjTextBox` is string. try this: `<%=MyTextBox1.ClientID %>`

Comment: just try this var objTextBox= $("#<%=ObjTextBox.ClientID %>")

Comment: MyTextBox1 is name of custom control put inside webform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property on your custom control as:

```
public string TextBoxClientID
{
   get 
   { 
     return objTextBox.ClientID; 
   }
}
```

And use this property as:

```
var objTextBox = document.getElementById('<%=MyTextBox1.TextBoxClientID %>');
```